# Ubuntu very slow after deleting old kernel images and cleanup

Tags: apt, kernel, cleanup

Yesterday the partition where I have my SO got full so I typed this command: `dpkg --get-selections|grep 'linux-image*'|awk '{print $1}'|egrep -v "linux-image-$(uname -r)|linux-image-generic" |while read n;do apt-get -y remove $n;done`. 
to delete old kernel images and did a clean up.
So today when I turned it on the system was running really slow like 1 frame per second and it didn’t automatically connect to the WiFi.
What can I do to fix it??
Thanks for your help guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands and report back any errors found:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -f
```

If errors were reported as being fixed then reboot and see if speed improves.

You might consider posting a comment under the answer you followed. Briefly summarize the problem and include a link back to your question here.

Comment: I get five errors, Err:1 http:... temporary fail to solve repository, Err:2 http:... and 5 more. Also I get more errors like: Fail to obtain repository. When doing sudo apt install -f I get: 0 updated, 0 new files will install 0 will be deleted and 9 are not updated. I think the problem is that I’m not connected to internet but I don’t know how to connect, it should do it automatically because the WiFi is saved but it doesn’t.

Comment: Boot with a Live USB and see if WiFi works ok using it.

Comment: Yes it does work fine